Luke 17:5 - Luke 17:19 Did Jesus really answer how faith is increased as Disciples requested?

Luke 17:5 And the apostles said unto the Lord, Increase our faith.

It appears that Jesus never gave a direct answer to this although it is not question type of request by the disciples. Or did Jesus answer in an encoded manner?
Interestingly enough, Jesus closes the passage at:

Luke 17:19 - And he said unto him, Arise, go thy way: thy faith hath
made thee whole.

How to interpret Jesus take on increasing faith?

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Jesus certainly did answer the cry about a need for more faith. The way to understand Jesus' answer is to get rid of human ideas about faith and grasp the kind of faith Jesus and the Father require.
First, it has nothing to do with our ideas of "quantity" - as if "more of it" will do the trick. Even a tiny amount will result in miracles. A mustard-seed of faith will move massive trees by the roots and toss them into the sea. Spadefuls are not required. That's what Jesus immediately impressed on them, in verse 6.
Second, it is WHO even a tiny bit of faith is in that matters. It is not in our own powers, or maturity, or that of an apparently spiritually stronger person. It has to be faith in God and Christ alone. Faith in their word - their promises - has to be unshakable.
Third, it has to be faith that is gifted to us by God - Ephesians 2:8. We cannot work it up in ourselves, nor can other people. Already is is obvious that man-made ideas about faith are stumbling-blocks to real faith.
Fourth, the exercise of God-given faith has to be a constant in our lives, not just something we think to "pull out of our spiritual tool-box" as and when we suppose it is required:
"The just shall live by faith" - Romans 1:17.
"All that is not of faith is sin" - Romans 14:23.
"Even the righteousness of God which is by faith of Jesus Christ" - Romans 3:22.
That last text is particularly important, given how many modern translations have changed it to "faith in Jesus Christ" when the Greek text shows it is the faith exercised by Christ that we have to trust totally. It is his faith that counts for God's righteousness, because we have no righteousness of our own. All the focus is on "Jesus the author and finisher of faith" - Hebrews 12:2. Notice how the word "our" [faith] is not in the Greek text? It is Jesus alone we have to go to, and to abide in, to have saving faith that pleases God. Then our faith will be strong and glorifying to God.
Now that those points have been cleared up, it should be possible to go back to the text in question and grasp Jesus' answer - free from our false notions about faith - and see how clearly he dealt with the perceived problem of insufficient faith. It is only by hearing the words of truth in God's word, and believing them, that faith will begin and continue: "So then faith cometh by hearing, and hearing by the word of God" - Romans 10:17. Previously blocked-up spiritual ears have to be unblocked by the power of the Holy Spirit working in those who have the word of God proclaimed to them, and then faith will come. But who today is proclaiming the pure gospel of the faith of Christ (vs. 14)? And who, having heard the pure gospel, will then do it (Ephesians 4:29)? Only those who have God-given faith in their hearts (Mark 11:23 cf. Luke 17:6, back to the text in question). God-given faith is evidenced by our being obedient to God's word. It is more obedience that is needed. Obedient faith honours God, and God honours those who honour him - 1 Samuel 2:30 & John 12:26.

I do not see these verses as telling the disciples how to increase their faith.  I believe He is rather chastising them a bit for their continued lack of it.
Luke 9:41

And Jesus answering said, O faithless and perverse generation, how long shall I be with you, and suffer you? Bring thy son hither.

One of the 10 lepers in the verses you cited glorified God and was recognized by Christ because of the faith he already had.
There are clearly some today who are weaker in faith than others, but God has received all believers regardless of where they stand in their own walk in faith.
Romans 14:1-3

Him that is weak in the faith receive ye, but not to doubtful disputations.
2 For one believeth that he may eat all things: another, who is weak, eateth herbs.
3 Let not him that eateth despise him that eateth not; and let not him which eateth not judge him that eateth: for God hath received him.

Paul instructs us of how we grow in faith today:
Romans 10:17

So then faith cometh by hearing, and hearing by the word of God.

Our faith is increased as we hear and accept more and more of God's Word, the Bible, which is authored by the Spirit.  One cannot grow in spiritual understanding without first hearing the Word of God.  Faith of the believer increases as the believer hears and understands the teachings of the Spirit through scriptural study.
2 Timothy 2:15

Study to shew thyself approved unto God, a workman that needeth not to be ashamed, rightly dividing the word of truth.

The writer of Hebrews points out that without first having faith there is no pleasing God.
Hebrews 11:6

But without faith it is impossible to please him: for he that cometh to God must believe that he is, and that he is a rewarder of them that diligently seek him.


The section, as I see it, begins with 17:1 and ends at 17:10. The text starting at 17:5 is the disciples' response to Jesus' statements in 17:1-4.  Verse 17:11 changes a geographic location which, in an oral culture, is often a rhetorical signal that a topic is changing.
To summarize 17:1-4:

Don't put other people in a position where they are forced to sin.  This comes from the use of the word σκάνδαλον (a snare trap). This is an indictment against those who exercise power, for making other people's decisions for them ensnares them, causing them to fail.
When someone sins against you, you need to work through it with the
intent of leading to their repentance.  I take this as being distinct from and opposed to an eye-for-an-eye justice.

The disciple's response to that is to ask for help regarding their faith. For how does anyone accomplish anything without wielding power, but They certainly didn't want to be among those who cause others to sin (thrown into the sea was motivation enough); also, dealing with other's sin, like others wrongly wielding power, is simply quite hard to begin with (but adding to that the purpose of letting the sinner off the hook, or so it seems).
And, given the way the disciples appear to ask, it suggests to us that there are different amounts of faith.  As if Barney has a level 7 faith, and I'm only at a level 4. "I gotta work harder," we might think. Unfortunately, that forces us to interpret 'faith' as a 'work'.  A complete contradiction to the Gospel.
I think the whole idea of faith having a quantity attribute is quite broken.  So, this is one of the places in the New Testament where I think it is best to understand πίστις (faith, trust, belief) as 'commitment' or its synonyms 'loyalty' or 'allegiance'.  This actually aligns quite well with James 2:17.  For example, what if that verse is translated as:

So also commitment, if it doesn't produce anything, is dead, being by itself.

We've probably all experienced someone's so-called commitment that has no follow-through.  In other words, committing to something and doing nothing means you haven't committed.   The concepts of loyalty and allegiance fit just as well.  Also, Jesus teaches this point in the Parable of 'The Two Sons' (Matthew 28:21-32).  One son commits to do the work and does nothing; the other doesn't commit and does.  So, which one was actually committed to their father?  Which one showed loyalty?  So, the concept of commitment, loyalty, or allegiance is a core element of faith (πίςτις).
This doesn't mean that works saves.  That's the beauty of the gospel.  All that is required is the commitment.  So, if you're going to die within the hour, salvation based only on belief (aka faith) is assured.  You don't have to crawl out of your deathbed and go do something good. The thief on a cross can testify to that (Luke 23:43). He came down off that cross dead, having done nothing worthy.  He simply, and only, made a commitment. However, in the normal course of events, faith without works, being alone, is a dead faith.  No works is in reality proof that no commitment was ever made.  It's as if you've made a commitment to not respond to such great grace.
So, increasing one's faith as if it is a quantity that can be worked-up to higher levels is a contradiction to the gospel itself.
The concept we label 'commitment' explains how salvation is by faith alone (the Reformation call of solo fide). Commitment really doesn't accomplish anything.  It does nothing.  It does no work.  But, this solo fide is all that God requires.  That's the beauty of the Gospel.
Now, I say all that to provide context for the two parts of the answer to the OP's question.  Because Jesus' answer is that commitment alone is all that is required; but simply and only meeting the requirement is not what is needed when living in a sinful world.  Recall that the disciples are responding to Jesus setting a high bar for dealing with sin; dangerously, one could risk being thrown into the sea with no possibility of escape (this is not a metaphor for hell, but that topic will take us too far afield).
Basically,

The Disciples are concerned that their level of commitment is not sufficient.
The Disciples don't understand that their actions are responses, they're not something that earns them any worth.

To solve these two problems, Jesus provides two explanations.
First, Jesus says that "faith the size of a mustard seed" is the amount needed.  In other words, in effect, he says, "the size of your commitment is irrelevant and makes no sense; you're asking the wrong question.  It's commitment or no commitment; there is no do." (Interesting, isn't it, the contrast with Yoda's statement--"Do or do not, there is no try."   Here's Jesus' answer, Luke 17:6 (NASB):

But the Lord said, “If you had faith the size of a mustard seed, you
could say to this mulberry tree, ‘Be uprooted and be planted in the
sea’; and it would obey you.

Meaning:  Commuting or not committing is decisive.  There's no composite or aggregate of faith and works.
Second, Jesus says that which seems harsh to us by today's standards.  But, we would be wise to understand our place.
Luke 17:10

So you too, when you do all the things which were commanded you, say,
‘We are unworthy slaves; we have done only that which we ought to have
done

Our works are always responsive to what the Master has commanded.  We're never in a place where we earn anything.  So, Jesus separates the two activities, one from the other.  The faith is separate from the works.  While the faith does nothing, it moves trees into the sea--the miraculous.  While works do necessary, productive work, there's nothing earned.  Our worth is not increased by obedience.  And, that's OK, since it's not about us anyway.  The Master is the center of our focus.
While it might seem strange to encourage faith in such a negative way (i.e. doing productive work means you're still unworthy), it places the right priority in the right place. It's faith, not works.  And, it defines faith correctly. It absolutely separates faith from works. And, faith is the key.  Who are you committed to?  That's the question.  Not, what have you done?  And it even makes obedience such that it doesn't earn anything either.  Obedience is simply the response we give for such a gracious gift of abundant life.
Works are a necessary result; they are not the cause.
Meaning:  Know your place; you're a servant, not a master.  This directs us in the opposite direction from exercising power over others.
In summary, the response to the Disciple's request to "increase our faith" is Jesus saying,

The so-called "size" of faith is irrelevant.  You're either committed to him or you're not.
A life of obedience, while necessary and expected, doesn't add to your worth.  So, there's no increase needed.


Some are actually weaker in faith than others.  We are all at different levels of our walk in it.  (Romans 14)

@MarkVestal  I think the topics in Romans 14 and Luke 17 are related, but developed differently.  Where Luke corrects wrong assumptions Romans guides towards right practice.  Take a quick look at 14:7-8.  Notice the connection between live and for the Lord.  'Live' speaks to practice, 'For the Lord' speaks to the prerequisite commitment.  So, that sentence echos both Luke 17:6 and Luke 17:7-10.  So, I guess the way I would word it is:  Faith (πἴστἰς) is either 'yes' or 'no'; Faithfulness (πἴστἰς) is weak or strong.  So, 'weak' in practice of faith--i.e. faithfulness.

Romans 14:1 "Weak in the faith" supports your notion, but I would still argue that "increasing one's faith" or increasing in one's "faithfulness" is then not contradictory to the gospel.  I do not disagree that faith is a gift, but that gift is received as we hear and believe the Spirit (study the Bible).  Therefore, we are gifted faith upon following the Spirit.  Faith, as too many claim, is not just randomly appropriated to whom God wills it to be.  It is gifted to anyone who hears and believes what they have heard of the Spirit...in God's perfect written Word.  Thanks for the clarification!

First, the two verses about faith quoted by the OP are contained in two separate incidents, probably a few days apart at least.  The first is part of a conversation with the disciples; the second is part of a conversation a few days later with one of the 10 healed lepers.
Second, the NT does not say that we (ourselves) increase faith - faith is a gift of God as the following:

Eph 2:8 - For it is by grace you have been saved through faith, and this not from yourselves; it is the gift of God
Acts 3:16 - By faith in the name of Jesus, this man whom you see and know has been made strong. It is Jesus’ name and the faith that comes through Him that has given him this complete healing in your presence.
2 Peter 1:1 - Simon Peter, a servant and apostle of Jesus Christ, To those who through the righteousness of our God and Savior Jesus Christ have received a faith as precious as ours

This is seen in many other ways as well. The centrality of faith, or better, trust, in the Christian’s life is best illustrated by examining the use of the phrase “faith of Jesus” which occurs five times.  Rom 3:22, 26, Gal 2:16, 3:22, Rev 14:12.  In all cases the Greek “pistis Iesou” (note the genitive) can be translated either as:

“Faith in Jesus” meaning the trust we have in Jesus to save us because we cannot do it ourselves.  That is, we allow Him to do for us that which we cannot do for ourselves.
“Faithfulness of Jesus” (more literally correct) meaning the trustworthiness and faithfulness of Jesus Himself that He exercised on our behalf to save us; and that we imitate in order to receive the merits and benefits of Jesus.  See especially 2 Tim 2:13.

In my judgement it is not necessary to decide between these two as both are intended.  That is, we trust Jesus to be trustworthy.  There is a similar situation with “Faith of God” in Mark 11:22, Rom 3:3.
Luke 17:5
In Luke 17:5, when the disciples asked Jesus to increase their faith, they were asking Jesus to do this work, not how to do it themselves.  Jesus answered in the next verse:

V6: And the Lord answered, “If you have faith [better, "trust"] the
size of a mustard seed, you can say to this mulberry tree, ‘Be
uprooted and planted in the sea,’ and it will obey you.


When Jesus responded to His disciples in Luke 17:6, using the mustard seed as an analogy, I believe it was a direct and intentional answer. His disciples should have already understood the significance of faith, even beginning as small as a mustard seed, from the parables in Matthew 13:31, Mark 4:31 and Luke 13:19. On another occasion, Jesus privately explained to them the meaning of the parable of the sower (Matthew 13:16-23, Make 4:13-20, Luke 8:11-15).
Through this response, Jesus reminded them that faith is not something given to them but something that must grow within their hearts.
Luke 17:7-19 does not seem relevant to this narrative. The parallel passage in Matthew 17:19-20 does not align with these verses. In fact, Luke 17:7-19 is unique to Luke's Gospel, and likely pertains to a different occasion altogether.
